# How do you create a local VGO application module

Tags: go, vgo

Every example I've seen with `vgo` so far requires you to write your module, upload it then create a new application module to test a basic module.

Is there a way to test a module by skipping the repo step and just adding a package main to your module just to spit out something to the console?

I've tried creating my dummy module `module "example.com/m"` adding a dummy subpackage to the `package example` in `/example/testing.go` then added a simple main.go and tried importing the example package from my dummy module to no avail.

If I had no internet, I'd be pretty lost with the vgo workflow (I'm lost without it tbh)

Comment: Use `replace` in your module file to specify the path to the module.

Comment: @TimCooper I've tried `replace example.com/m/example => ./example` and I'm not getting anywhere. You have a real example that I can work from.

Comment: I have a set of debug utility code that I import just during debuging. Previously I just had it in the GOPATH and I could import it. I moved the code outside of GOPATH, ran `go mod init`. But I can't import it into the project (also outside of GOPATH) I want to use it in. HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically vgo allows you to include `package main` in the root, but by doing this you can only use 'main' packages in the root directory of your vgo project because golang only permits one package name per folder. Which is fine since you can remove the main file later if you want.

**Answer**

- Create a `package main` file in the root directory of your vgo project with a `fn main`
- Create any amount of sub packages in your vgo project ex.: `package example` in an `example` sub folder. For fun create an exported function that prints out "Hello World" and call it "WorldGreeting"
- Now in your main file you can import this package by calling your module name followed by the sub package name. So for instance if your module name is `bitbucket.com/User/MyVGOPackage` then you would import your sub package in the main file like `import "bitbucket.com/User/MyVGOPackage/example"` then call your function inside of main `example.WorldGreeting()`
- Build using `go build` to build the full directory (in case you have more main packages in the directory) and vgo will spit out an exe called "MyVGOPackage.exe"

Tip: If you just want to create an application without a weird module name just rename your module to something simple like "MyApplication" and vgo will understand your imports perfectly. then go back and replace "bitbucket.com/User/MyVGOPackage/example" to "MyApplication/example" and everything will build normally. Jetbrain's GoLand IDE understands this usage perfectly so give it a shot if vs code is having issues auto completing.